# creating an app babycall, how can I link/route iphone with device bluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I have a technical problem that I have spent several weeks trying to solve but I am not able to do, so I ask for help.

I'm developing an app so that it can function as "**babycall**" along with the app have our bluetooth device where the mother can leave with the baby.

Babycall bluetooth connects with my iPhone through adjustments to share all the multimedia content, `funcionamente` is very similar to the helmets have a microphone.

**CURRENTLY**: I connect and play all the sounds of my iPhone in babycall, incluiendo the sounds of my app.

**PROBLEM**: I have to link/route my iPhone with babycall follows:

**iphone-microphone -> sends sound -> babycall-speakers**

**iphone-media -> sends sound -> babycall-speakers**

**babycall-microphone -> sends sound -> iphone-speakers**

As I read in the documentation of apple, it seems to be done with **AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute** but I have not been able to apply this setting.

Please, can you help me?

I am developing in Objective-C.

Thank you.

Comment: So you get some error while routing sound on babycall-speakers from iphone or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, we have been able to link with one another, but what I can not do stream, I have to record and then play, I can not do continuous. :(

Comment: if possible, I have to look at code to check if everything is configured properly. I can not guess why streaming is not working.

Comment: We have not found a solution, communication with bluetooth helmets are not synchronized, you can only do one thing at a time, recording and playback.